# Extract a single value of dataframe by passing 2 variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a lookup table and I want to extract a single value of this lookup table by passing two variables of my data frame. One variable matches the row (P=P1) and the second variable matches the columns of the lookup table (A, B and C).

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
#lookup table
lookup_table <- data.table(P=c(2,4,6,8),
                           A=c(10:13),
                           B=c(20:23),
                           C=c(30,33))
#my data frame that I want to incorporate the lookup table values
my_data <- data.table(P1=c(4,6,8,2,6,8,4,2,6,4),
                      var1=c("B","C","A","B","C","A","A","B","C","A"))
```

All I want is to add the respective lookup_table values in my data frame.

I derived the following function, but it is not working.

```
get_from_lookup_table <- function(P,var1){
  lookup_table[P == P,..var1]
}
```

When I execute the function and try to add the new column to my data frame all the values appear as multi-column.

```
my_data$look_up_table_value <- get_from_lookup_table(my_data$P1,my_data$var1)
> my_data
    P1 var1 look_up_table_value
 1:  4    B      <multi-column>
 2:  6    C      <multi-column>
 3:  8    A      <multi-column>
 4:  2    B      <multi-column>
 5:  6    C      <multi-column>
 6:  8    A      <multi-column>
 7:  4    A      <multi-column>
 8:  2    B      <multi-column>
 9:  6    C      <multi-column>
10:  4    A      <multi-column>
```

It apperas a simple task, but my data frame has more than 50000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a vectorized approach in `base R`.  Convert the `data.table` to `data.frame`, use the `row/col`umn indexing by `match`ing the columns of dataset with the lookup_table 'P' column and the names of the lookup_table to create a `matrix` or row/column index.  Use that to extract the corresponding values

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(my_data)
df1$look_up_table_value <- as.data.frame(lookup_table)[cbind(match(df1$P1, 
       lookup_table$P), match(df1$var1, names(lookup_table)))]
```

-output

```
df1
   P1 var1 look_up_table_value
1   4    B                  21
2   6    C                  30
3   8    A                  13
4   2    B                  20
5   6    C                  30
6   8    A                  13
7   4    A                  11
8   2    B                  20
9   6    C                  30
10  4    A                  11
```

---

Or another option is to do a join and `get` the value of column by looping over the sequence

```
my_data[, look_up_table_value := my_data[, rn := seq_len(.N)][lookup_table, 
       on = .(P1 = P)][order(rn)][,get(var1), 1:nrow(my_data)]$V1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`mapply` allows to use your original code:

```
get_from_lookup_table <- function(P,var1){
  unlist(mapply(function(row,col) lookup_table[P==row,..col],P,var1))
}

get_from_lookup_table(my_data$P1,my_data$var1)
# B  C  A  B  C  A  A  B  C  A 
# 21 30 13 20 30 13 11 20 30 11 


my_data$look_up_table_value <- get_from_lookup_table(my_data$P1,my_data$var1)

my_data

   P1 var1 look_up_table_value
 1:  4    B                  21
 2:  6    C                  30
 3:  8    A                  13
 4:  2    B                  20
 5:  6    C                  30
 6:  8    A                  13
 7:  4    A                  11
 8:  2    B                  20
 9:  6    C                  30
10:  4    A                  11
```

However, this is absolutely not efficient:

```
a <- function() {
  df1 <- as.data.frame(my_data)
  df1$look_up_table_value <- as.data.frame(lookup_table)[cbind(match(df1$P1, 
                                                                     lookup_table$P), match(df1$var1, names(lookup_table)))]
  
}
w <- function() {my_data$look_up_table_value <- get_from_lookup_table(my_data$P1,my_data$var1)}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a(),w())

Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq     max neval
  a()   124.8   161.20   308.658   209.0   227.80  5563.0   100
  w() 11300.6 11973.35 13317.676 12340.1 13528.35 26613.7   100
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to derive a function to use in future works. But now is also possible